# Countdown Timer Problem

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I am working with a countdown timer and have it set so that it is able to be set by the user. When the timer gets to 00:00 its supposed to say "done!". For some reason I'm getting the "done!" right after I start the timer. After hitting pause and resume it shows my counter counting down but I'm not so sure that customers are gonna be cool with this. Can anyone tell why I'm having this problem? Thanks.

```
        package score.keeper.basketball;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class Score extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Button Button01;
    private Button Button02;
    private Button Button03;
    private Button Button04;
    private TextView TextView01;
    private TextView TextView02;
    private TextView TextView03;
    private TextView TextView06;
    private Spinner Spinner01;
    private Spinner Spinner02;

    private TextView Team01;
    private TextView Team02;

    TextView timeDisplay;
    int state = 0;
    int length;
    long startTime = 0;
    long currentTime = 0;
    long timeElapsed = 0;
    long timeRemaining = 0;
    long prevTimeRemaining = 0;
    Button control;
    MyCount counter;

    String[] goal={"Three", "Foul", "Two"};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        Button02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        Button03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        Button04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);

        TextView01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        TextView02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        TextView03 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
        TextView06 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView06);
        Team01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
        Team02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView05);

        Team01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Score.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.setteamname);
                    dialog.setTitle("Team Name");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);

                    final EditText teamName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.teamName);

                    Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setText);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            String teamName2 = teamName.getText().toString();

                            Team01.setText("" + teamName2);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                        });     
                    dialog.show();
            }});

        Team02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Score.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.setteamname);
                dialog.setTitle("Team Name");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);

                final EditText teamName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.teamName);

                Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setText);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String teamName3 = teamName.getText().toString();

                        Team02.setText("" + teamName3);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                    });     
                dialog.show();
        }});

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, goal);

        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);


        Button01.setOnLongClickListener(subtractLeft);
        Button02.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){my_func1();}});
        Button03.setOnLongClickListener(subtractRight);
        Button04.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v){my_func2();}});

        timeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        timeDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Score.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Set Time");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);

                final EditText min = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.min);

                final EditText sec = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sec);

                Button btn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.positive);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){

                        int min2 = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString());
                        int sec2 = Integer.parseInt(sec.getText().toString());

                        {length = (((min2 * 60) + sec2) * 1000);

                        dialog.dismiss();}

                    }});


                dialog.show();} 

                });
        counter = new MyCount(length, 100); 
        control = (Button) findViewById(R.id.control);

      }

      public void control(View view) {
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
          startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          counter.start();
          control.setText(R.string.pause);
          state = 1;
          break;
        case 1:
          // pause
          currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;

          if (prevTimeRemaining == 0)
            timeRemaining = length - timeElapsed;
          else
            timeRemaining = prevTimeRemaining - timeElapsed;
          counter.cancel();
          timeDisplay.setText(formatTime(timeRemaining));
          control.setText(R.string.resume);
          prevTimeRemaining = timeRemaining;

          // resume
          counter = new MyCount(timeRemaining, 100);
          state = 0;
          break;
        case 2:
          prevTimeRemaining = 0;
          counter = new MyCount(length, 100);
          control.setText(R.string.start);
          timeDisplay.setText(R.string.timer);
          state = 0;
        }
      }

      public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
          super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
          timeDisplay.setText("done!");
          state = 2;
          control.setText(R.string.restart);
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          timeDisplay.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
        }
      }




      public String formatTime(long millis) {
          String output = "00:00";
          long seconds = millis / 1000;
          long minutes = seconds / 60;
          // long hours = minutes / 60;

          seconds = seconds % 60;
          minutes = minutes % 60;
          // hours = hours % 60;

          String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
          String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
          // String hoursD = String.valueOf(hours); 

          if (seconds < 10)
            secondsD = "0" + seconds;
          if (minutes < 10)
            minutesD = "0" + minutes;
          // if (hours < 10)
            // hoursD = "0" + hours;

          output = minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
          return output;
        }



    public void setSpinner02(Spinner spinner02) {
        Spinner02 = spinner02;
    }

    public Spinner getSpinner02() {
        return Spinner02;
    }

    public void setSpinner01(Spinner spinner01) {
        Spinner01 = spinner01;
    }

    public Spinner getSpinner01() {
        return Spinner01;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
    if ("Three".equals(goal[position]))
    {TextView03.setText("3");}

    if ("Foul".equals(goal[position]))
    {TextView03.setText("1");}

    if ("Two".equals(goal[position]))
    {TextView03.setText("2");}

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView03.setText("2");
        TextView06.setText("2");

    }


    void my_func1() {
        int scoreLeft; 
        int addOne;
        int scoreLeftTotal;

        addOne = Integer.parseInt(TextView03.getText().toString());
        scoreLeft = Integer.parseInt(TextView01.getText().toString());

        scoreLeftTotal = (scoreLeft + addOne);

        TextView01.setText("" + scoreLeftTotal);
        }


   void my_func2() {
            int scoreRight = Integer.parseInt(TextView02.getText().toString());
            int addOne = Integer.parseInt(TextView03.getText().toString());

            {int scoreRightTotal = (scoreRight + addOne);

            TextView02.setText("" + scoreRightTotal);
            }

    }
    private OnLongClickListener subtractLeft = new OnLongClickListener() { 
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        int scoreLeft = Integer.parseInt(TextView01.getText().toString());
        int addOne = Integer.parseInt(TextView03.getText().toString());

        {int scoreLeftTotal = (scoreLeft - addOne);

        TextView01.setText("" + scoreLeftTotal);
        }

        return true; 
        }
};
private OnLongClickListener subtractRight = new OnLongClickListener() { 
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    int scoreRight = Integer.parseInt(TextView02.getText().toString());
    int addOne = Integer.parseInt(TextView03.getText().toString());

    {int scoreLeftTotal = (scoreRight - addOne);

    TextView02.setText("" + scoreLeftTotal);
    }

    return true; 
    }
};

public void OnClick(View view) {
    if (view==Team01){
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Score.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.setteamname);
        dialog.setTitle("Team Name");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        final EditText teamName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.teamName);

        teamName.setText(R.id.TextView04);

        Button btn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.setText);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                teamName.getText().toString();

                Team01.setText("" + teamName);

                }

            });

        dialog.show();} 

        };

}
```

Comment: This is too much code and a little vague question - you really need to narrow down the part that is causing a problem by debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chopping off the initialisation code confused me there as it too a while to notice your braces didn't balance...

it looks like you are creating your counter and initialising it outside of both of the onclick functions. At this stage Length is zero.

when you click the start button length gets set to a valid time but the timer is not reinitialised so it starts with its previously set value of zero and fires onFinish straight away.

When you press pause the correct remaining time is calculated and which is then passed onto the new counter you create when you resume which then proceeds to count down normally.

Moving  `counter = new MyCount(length, 100);` up to directly after `dialog.show();}` should ensure that the counter gets initialised when the set timer button is clicked and fix the problem.

Comment: I've added the whole code if that helps. I tried what you said but it is still doing it. I can't figure out why its doing it now because earlier it wasn't doing this. I had the time set for a fixed interval though if its possible that that would make the difference.

Comment: Did you move the counter=new... inside of the Time set onClick handler or is it as shown above? It must be inside the handler (i.e. between Dialog.show(); and the closing brace"}") or it won't get initialised.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. You definitly had the right idea. It looks like putting it after the dialog.dismiss(); works. So its dialog.dismiss();
            counter = new MyCount(length, 100);}